How to download file from wwwroot folder?
I created a button on a Radzen page to download a file inside the wwwroot folder. This file is related to a row inside my table on SQL Server database (table name is : Tbl_Tickets).
The file path and file name is saved inside my table in SQL Server database. I created an object of the table named it (tblTicket) to filter inside my wwwroot folder by ticket_Id column.
This is the error that I'm receiving:

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Administrator/source/repos/Tickets/V05/wwwroot

This is the code of the button in my Blazor page:
 <RadzenRow>
     <button @onclick="DownloadFileFromURL"> Download Files</button>
 </RadzenRow>

This is the function of DownloadFileFromURL:
<script>
    window.triggerFileDownload = (fileName, url) => {
      const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
      anchorElement.href = url;
      anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
      anchorElement.click();
      anchorElement.remove();
    }
</script>

And this is the code:
@code {
private async Task DownloadFileFromURL()
{
var fileName = $"{tblTicket.AttchedFileName}";
var fileURL = $"{environment.WebRootPath}";
await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("triggerFileDownload", fileName, fileURL);
}

And for you information I Injected this
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@inject IWebHostEnvironment environment


"But it doesn't work." - is not a sufficient problem description. Does that mean there is an error? Simply nothing happening? Downloading not what you expect to be downloaded? Which is it?

Side note: please don't drip feed information into your question. Before you post it include all the information at once. Your initial revision was missing 2 code blocks you stated were included. Also, some basic capitalisation goes a long way for readability.

this is the error appears to me(  Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/Administrator/source/repos/Tickets/V05/wwwroot)

Seems like a simple path evaluation mistake to me. Somehow the full local path got transmitted. Of course, the client cannot access that.

This is a security issue. Today, most browsers do not allow accessing file:// URLs in a http(s):// webpage.
Although there are some workarounds (such as using extensions or encoding files as base64), the best practice is to host the file you want to download on a website and then use a http(s):// URL to access it.
If this wwwroot folder is the root folder of your running website, you can simply set:
anchorElement.href = '/' + fileName;


thanx my friend . it worked for me and the file has been downloaded . but the size is smaller than the original file on my wwwroot/upload folder and not opened

Amend: you still need to specify the filename in href.

thank you it worked now my friend.  but just download any file with size 115 kb. so if the file is bigger than 115 kb it will not open. what should i do?

This sounds like an issue related to app configuration (or limitation?). I tried downloading a 247kb image using the code you provided in a new blazor project and it worked. I suggest you to create a new question and attach a [mre].

@DarkBee the OP has posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79237973/after-downloading-a-file-from-wwwroot-folder-in-myblazor-app-it-only-get-file-wi
