after downloading a file from wwwroot folder in myblazor app it only get file with 115 kb no matter what is the file size
I created a button on a Radzen page to download a file inside the wwwroot folder. This file is related to a row inside my table on SQL Server database (table name is : Tbl_Tickets).
The file path and file name is saved inside my table in SQL Server database. I created an object of the table named it (tblTicket) to filter inside my wwwroot folder by ticket_Id column.so that i can get the original file from my wwwroot folder.
This is the code of the button in my Blazor page:

 @page "/AddTicket-Attachment"
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@inject IWebHostEnvironment environment

<RadzenRow>
     <button @onclick="DownloadFileFromURL"> Download Files</button>
 </RadzenRow>

<script>
    window.triggerFileDownload = (fileName, url) => {
      const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
      anchorElement.href = '/';
      anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
      anchorElement.click();
      anchorElement.remove();
    }
</script>

And this is the code:
@code {
private async Task DownloadFileFromURL()
{
var fileName = $"{tblTicket.AttchedFileName}";
var fileURL = $"{environment.WebRootPath}";
await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("triggerFileDownload", fileName, fileURL);
}

it is working and download the file.
but the problem is ( if the file size is  less than 115 kb it can be downloaded and opened with no problem. but if the file size was more than 115 kb it just can be downloaded with 115 kb of size and can't be opened ). so can any one tell me what the problem is in my code

"115 kb it will not open. what should i do?" - Open the file in notepad and see if any errors (and/or extra output) are visible inside the file

Not directly related to your issue, but MS Docs say if your file's <250MB (which it sounds like it is; unless that's just for a POC) you should instead use a stream to download.  More info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-9.0#download-from-a-stream

Regarding your issue, RichardDeeming's answer covers it... i.e. the url says where to fetch your file from; so you need to put a path (relative or absolute) to the file.  filename just says what name to give the downloaded file (i.e. it can be different to the source filename).  The 115kb file probably isn't the first 115kb of the file you're expecting - it's just the contents of the root of your site (whatever's returned by calling get /) written into a file with the given filename.

First problem:
anchorElement.href = '/';

Your JavaScript function always tries to download the root of your site. You presumably meant to use the url parameter instead:
anchorElement.href = url;

Second problem:
var fileURL = $"{environment.WebRootPath}";

Your C# function passes the WebRootPath as the URL to download. That won't work; the property returns the physical path of the wwwroot folder on the server that's hosting it - eg: C:\Path\To\Your\Site\wwwroot\.
You need to pass a URL that the client can use to download the specified file - for example: /downloads/The-File-To-Download.pdf.
How you construct that URL will depend on where the downloads are stored, and what data you have in your database. At a guess, something like this:
var fileName = tblTicket.AttchedFileName;
var fileURL = $"/downloads/{tblTicket.AttchedFileName}";


I thought so too but the OP states  "if the file size is less than 115 kb it can be downloaded"

@HenkHolterman Given the code provided, it certainly won't be downloading the expected file. So it's a question of whether the code shown is not the code that's running, or the file that's "successfully" downloaded is not actually what it was expected to be.
